# Multithreaded compression, random access and on-the-fly reading

Tags: zlib

I have a program running on linux which generates thousand of text files. I want these files to be packed into a single (compressed) file.

The compressed file will later be opened by a C program, which needs to access specific files inside that container, in a random fashion.

The whole thing is working as follows:

- Linux program generates thousands of small files
- `zip -9 out.zip *`
- C program with libzip accesing specific files inside .zip, depending on what the user requests. These reads are done on memory (no writing decompressed files to disk).

Works great. However, it takes about ~20 minutes for the compression to finish. Because such compression runs on a 40-core server, I have been experimenting with lbzip2 with excellent results in terms of both compression ratio and speed. I have also used `zip -0` to pack all the .bz files into a single .zip container, which I assume is a better option than tar because of random access.

So my question is, how can I read .bz files compressed inside a .zip file? As far as I can tell, `gzopen` takes a file path as first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just stick with your current zip format for random access. Run separate zip commands individually on each text file to turn them into many single entry zip files. Launch all those at once, and your 40 cores will be kept busy until done. Once done, use [zipmerge](https://libzip.org/documentation/zipmerge.html) to combine them all into a single zip file.